# Using variable inside a class function defintion, which created in other class function | python

Tags: python, python-2.7

how do i use variable in class function, which i created in other, without using `global` and `return`? there is some other ways?

```
class functions:
    def func1():

        x=[1,2]

    def func2():

        print x
func1()
func2()
```

output:

```
[1,2]
```

the real problem:

```
class WebPage:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename=filename


    def process(self):

        toproc=open(self.filename,'r')
        lines=toproc.readlines()
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip()
        head=[]
        body=[]

        process....
        head=[headline]
        body=[sitebody]

    def printedheadbody:
        print head
        print body
```

Comment: ``def class:`` is invalid. Did you mean ``class foo:``?

Comment: They aren't currently class methods; they are instance methods, but missing the `self` parameter. What are you actually trying to achieve?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them attributes and use self.head, self.body, you also don't need to call readlines, you can iterate directly over the file object and call `line.rstrip()` as you go if you want to strip. You should also inherit from object in python2 to support new style classes.

```
class WebPage(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.head = []
        self.body = []

    def process(self): 
        with open(self.filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                # use self.head,self.body     

    def printedheadbody(self):
        print self.head
        print self.body
```

Without using `self` in your methods, you basically have static methods which won't allow you to refer to the attributes with `self`.

To access the methods create an instance and call the methods in order:

```
w = WebPage("foo.html")

w.process()
w.printedheadbody()
```

You also don't need the print method, you could access the attributes with the instance and just print each:

```
w = WebPage("foo.html")

w.process()
print(w.head)
print(w.body)
```

The attributes could also be created in the process method:

```
def process(self):
    self.head=[]
    self.body=[]
    with open(self.filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            ....
```

but you would need to make sure you called process before you ever tried to acesss them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `self` in a class. This variable is an instance of itself.

```
class functions:
    def func1(self):
        self.x = [1,2]
    def func2(self):
        print self.x

functions_1 = functions()
functions_1.func1()
functions_1.func2()

>> [1,2]
```